# connect mysql database in webserver with c# program in windows

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a website.  My database is MySQL and now I want to write a program with C# that the user can use this app to upload their file to my website

How can I connect a C# program in Windows with a MySQL database on a web server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) with [MySql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net).
Here's tutorial how to use it:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

As alternative you can use NHibernate: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26123/NHibernate-and-MySQL-A-simple-example

Also, as SamiHuutoniemi mentioned, you can use MySql connector without ORM, by simply using data reader: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html

**Update**: Ups, looks like I misunderstood the question. Short answer is - you don't wish to communicate directly with your website's database from desktop, as it involves many issues, one of them is security - you will need to open your database access from outside. I would suggest to make a page (web service) on your existing website that would accept requests from c# client and transform those requests into actions with database.
Not sure what technology your current site is using, but if that is PHP, this page lists few of them: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/

Comment: tnx,but my question is about connect windows app to website

Comment: for examole user open app and upload his file,then app connect to my website and sace his file to it

Comment: tnx again,how i start web service and connect this to my app

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use Entity Framework, you can also download [Oracle's .NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OleDbConnection to connect to mysql:
For example:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

    public class DataAccess
    {

          public void Connect(Action<OleDbConnection> action)
          {
                    using(var cnn=new OleDbConnection())
                   {
                       cnn.ConnectionString="Provider=MySqlProv;Data Source=ServerName;User id=UserName;Password=Password;" 
                       cnn.Open();
                       action(cnn);
                   }
           }
    }
```

[Here](http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx) you can find more useful information.

Comment: tnx,but i wanna connect too mysql in website not in my computer

Comment: I didn't test it but I think if you put your IP as ServerName it works